# Split Out GoogleTag Manager Label Variables

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have created a tag within GTM which as part of it's label returns various variables; page path, and various ID's

[GT Tag Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EEDOm.png)

As expected, when I view the events in Google Analytics, the label is one item.
[Event Action in GA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfxdz.png)

Ideally I would like them to be separate, so that reports in Analytics can be pivoted on these variables.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not as such, but you can create [hit-level](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) scoped [Custom Dimensions](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2709828?hl=en) and send them along with your event.

Custom dimensions are basically custom data fields that you can fill with arbitrary data (as long as each value is 150 byte or less). You can use them as secondary dimensions in standard reports, or in custom reports in GA (or in Google Data Studio).

Custom Dimensions will only work after you have configured them. If you need to work with existing data, you could use Google Data Studio, which directly connects to GA, and create calculated fields e.g. by splitting the value by the whitespace character and return the first (second, etc) bit. Data Studio is free, and is for the most part a much more capable reporting interface than GA itself, so it's worth a look.

Comment: Hi Eike, that was spot on, and worked a treat.

I wonder why I didn’t see that before ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. You have to export data and process them for example in Excel.